# UK driving licence

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

My Problem: I had a UK driving licence (year 2000) and travelled a lot since ( Europe) so no UK address, now I lost my licence and I am kind of homeless. How can I get my UK driving licence without having a UK address. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What kind of license do you have now?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

UK drivers licenses can be replaced, even from overseas, but only if the applicant resides in Great Britain. See [this UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/apply-online-to-replace-a-driving-licence) on getting a replacement license, which contains this text:

*Get a replacement provisional or full driving licence online with DVLA if yours gets lost, stolen, damaged or destroyed...*

*...To replace your licence you’ll need to:
be a resident of Great Britain (there’s a different service in Northern Ireland), not be disqualified from driving for any reason
pay £20 by MasterCard, Visa, Electron or Delta debit or credit card
provide addresses where you’ve lived for the last 3 years.*

Thus, to replace your lost license, you'll have to lie to DVLA about your residence. None of us would recommend that course of action.

Comment: Thank you David

Comment: @Weber You're welcome. If this answers your question — even though it isn't the response you wished — please upvote and mark the Answer as "Accepted."